# TcpClient connects fine, no errors, but no packets are received

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I'm making a multiplayer game in c#. I am trying to authenticate the users that play, and this is my code to read and write to the network stream:

```
    public async Task sendMessageAsync(Packet packet, TcpClient client)
    {
        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            Server.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
            return;
        }
        string stringPacket = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(packet);
        Server.WriteLine("Sending: " + stringPacket);
        byte[] bytePacket = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(stringPacket);
        byte[] messageLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int64)bytePacket.Length);
        byte[] message = new byte[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < messageLength.Length; i++)
        {
            message.Append(messageLength[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bytePacket.Length; i++)
        {
            message.Append(bytePacket[i]);
        }
        await client.GetStream().WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
        Server.WriteLine("Sent. (from sendMessage())");
    }
    public async Task<Packet> readMessageAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        ByteAssembler assembler = new ByteAssembler(8);
        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            Server.WriteLine("Client Disconnected");
            return new Packet(false);
        }
        while (!assembler.isFull)
        {
            Server.WriteLine("iteration");
            byte[] readingBytes = new byte[8];
            int usingInt = client.GetStream().Read(readingBytes, 0, 8);
            assembler.AddByteArray(readingBytes, usingInt);
        }
        byte[] byteMessageLength = assembler.Create();
        
        Int64 messageLength = (Int64)BitConverter.ToInt64(byteMessageLength, 0);

        Server.WriteLine("Reading " + messageLength.ToString() + " bytes of data");

        assembler.Clear(messageLength);

        while (client.Available < messageLength)
        {

        }

        while (!assembler.isFull)
        {
            byte[] byteMessage = new byte[messageLength];
            int usingInt = client.GetStream().Read(byteMessage, 0, byteMessage.Length);
            assembler.AddByteArray(byteMessage, usingInt);
        }
        string stringMessage = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(assembler.Create());

        //Server.WriteLine("Read.");

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Packet>(stringMessage);
    }
```

Byte Assembler Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Server.Classes
{
    public class ByteAssembler
    {
        public long targetLength;

        public List<byte[]> byteFragments = new List<byte[]>();
        public int currentLength = 0;

        public ByteAssembler(long targetLength)
        {
            this.targetLength = targetLength;
        }

        public void AddByteArray(byte[] array, int usingInt)
        {
            byteFragments.Add(SubArray<byte>(array, 0, usingInt));
            currentLength += usingInt;
        }

        public bool isFull => targetLength >= currentLength;

        public byte[] Create()
        {
            if (isFull)
            {
                byte[] returnValue = new byte[0];
                foreach(byte[] array in byteFragments)
                {
                    returnValue = Combine(returnValue, array);
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void Clear(long targetLength)
        {
            byteFragments = new List<byte[]>();
            currentLength = 0;
            this.targetLength = targetLength;
        }

        private byte[] Combine(params byte[][] arrays)
        {
            byte[] rv = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
            int offset = 0;
            foreach (byte[] array in arrays)
            {
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, rv, offset, array.Length);
                offset += array.Length;
            }
            return rv;
        }

        private T[] SubArray<T>(T[] array, int offset, int length)
        {
            T[] result = new T[length];
            Array.Copy(array, offset, result, 0, length);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call said function to read and write, the code throws no errors and outputs that it has sent information. But on the other machine (in this case the client. The client and server have identical send and receive functions) no message is received. Can anyone see any problems with the code? If you need more than this, I'm happy to post it.

P.S. I assume that it connects fine, because no errors are produced. I've also got other networking to work, but I'm not sure why this is working.

Comment: _"on the other machine...no message is received"_ -- TCP doesn't have messages. So what do you mean by _"no message is received"_? Please note that the code you posted is broken, because you fail to take into account the byte count returned by `Read()` and `ReadAsync()`. This could be part of the problem, or it could simply indicate lack of conceptual comprehension on your part that has led to an error elsewhere. Either way, without a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say exactly what's wrong, assuming there's something wrong with the code at all.

Comment: By "_on the other machine...no message is received_" I meant that there was no data to read in the stream. Also, would this work to check the length?
`if(await client.GetStream().ReadAsync(byteMessage, 0, byteMessage.Length) != messageLength)
{ //re-read? }`, or would you do a while statement checking if all data is read?

Comment: _"would this work to check the length?"_ -- no. You only get to read any given byte once. You can't just compare the byte count to some desired byte count. You have to handle reassembling any data partitioning you need, taking into account the amount of data received with each operation.

Comment: That's what I meant. Keep a value of how much is read, and a list of what has been read, and if the total is the `messageLength` or some other value, assemble it and then use it?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in the `sendMessageAsync` function, the code failed to append the two parts of the message. It resulted in a `byte[]` with nothing inside, and so it sent nothing.